# Order by result from another tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

HI i have skills tables as below

[image]

Various user add skills to their profile. Now i want to list all the skills  decreasing order of their uses. Like as below

Php(10) , ASP (5) , Perl(1)

Its means 10 user added php as their skill, 5 user ASP etc.

I have stored the skills in user table in skills column with comma separated

[image]

Comment: Where is your another table? Show it to us please.

Comment: From what information you provided, I would say your database structure is  a problem here. You might want to use a separate table for `skills`, `users` and `users_skills` in order to connect them. If you just store skills as comma separated values, you'd have to iterate over ALL users every time you want to get the total count.

Comment: Join both table when you get data then use explode.

Comment: I'll advice you not to store all the skills of a particular user in a single field to make your querying easier

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but what is the problem in it , if we can use find_in_set ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, name
from (
    select *, (select sum(1) from user u where find_in_set(s.id, u.skills)) as cnt
    from skills s
) t
order by cnt desc
-- limit 20
```

Comment: Here is my final query "select id, name , cnt
from (
    select *, (select sum(1) from users u where find_in_set(s.id, u.skills)) as cnt
    from skills s
) t
order by cnt desc limit 20"

Comment: Yes. Thanks you again @JPG

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have another table/relation to represent user_skills, that contains (for example) user_id and skill_id foreign keys, then you'd want to join this to the skills table and group the results similar to this:

```
select name, count(skill_id) as ranking
from skills join user_skills on skills.id = user_skills.skill_id
group by name
order by count(skill_id) desc, name asc;
```

It excludes skills which have not been selected by any users.  If you wanted to include those too, change the join to a left join.

Edit: With the original question updated to include the definition of the users table, then perhaps this would suffice.  Again you would need a left join to include skills that no users had picked.

```
select skills.name, count(users.id) as qty
from skills join users 
on locate(concat(',', skills.id, ','), concat(',', users.skills, ',')) > 0
group by skills.name
order by count(users.id) desc, skills.name asc;
```

Comment: Thank you @topdog, your second query is working fine.

Comment: I suspect the find_in_set() solution given by @JPG that you settled on using is more efficient/performant on a large data set than mine though, having looked at it.  Simpler to understand too.